# How to create list of datetimes without a leap day?

Tags: python, list, python-datetime

I need to create a list of datetime elements every minute from 2007-01-01 00:00 to 2016-01-01 00:00 but without February 29th. My code is the next:

```
dates = []
date0 = datetime(2007, 1, 1, 0, 0)
delta = td(minutes=1)
while date0 < datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0):
    if date0.date != date(2008, 2, 29) and date0.date != date(2012, 2, 29):
        dates.append(date0)
    date0 = date0 + delta
```

I should have a list for 9 years without 29.02. But my list of dates still contains February 29th of 2008 and 2012. I was trying to apply this code:

```
while date0 < datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0):
    if date0.month != 2 and date0.day != 29:
        dates.append(date0)
    date0 = date0 + delta
```

but as a result I have a list, which does not contain an appropriate number of days, anly 8 years and 14 days.
Do you have any solution or ideas about solving the issue?

Comment: That's potentially a huge number of `datatime`s (525K per year) and your overall approach to generating them is _very_ inefficient. Why do you want to do this? I suspect the might be an [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Agree with @martineau - but if you do need a date range then you could look into `pandas` - see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
if not (date0.month == 2 and date0.day == 29):
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the most simple way

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) a popular external data manipulation package:

```
In []:
import pandas as pd
dr = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2007', end='1/1/2016', freq='1min')
dates = dr[(dr.day != 29) | (dr.month != 2)]

len(dr), len(dates)

Out[]:
(4733281, 4730401)
```

This takes about `700ms` on my machine.

```
In []:
dates

Out[]:
DatetimeIndex(['2007-01-01 00:00:00', '2007-01-01 00:01:00', '2007-01-01 00:02:00', '2007-01-01 00:03:00',
               '2007-01-01 00:04:00', '2007-01-01 00:05:00', '2007-01-01 00:06:00', '2007-01-01 00:07:00',
               '2007-01-01 00:08:00', '2007-01-01 00:09:00',
               ...
               '2015-12-31 23:51:00', '2015-12-31 23:52:00', '2015-12-31 23:53:00', '2015-12-31 23:54:00',
               '2015-12-31 23:55:00', '2015-12-31 23:56:00', '2015-12-31 23:57:00', '2015-12-31 23:58:00',
               '2015-12-31 23:59:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=4730401, freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively efficient, Pure Python™, way to do it. The way leap days are skipped is simply by **not** including them in the `_DAYS_IN_MONTH` table (so nothing special is done depending on whether or not the current year being processed is a leap year).

I don't know precisely why you [think] you need this, but it might be better to do it via a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators), which would eliminate the need of storing so many `datatime` objects in memory at the same time.

```
from datetime import datetime

_DAYS_IN_MONTH = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]  # Ignores leap days.

start_year, end_year = 2007, 2016
dates = []
for year in range(start_year, end_year):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        for day in range(1, _DAYS_IN_MONTH[month-1]+1):
            for hour in range(0, 24):
                for minute in range(0, 60):
                    dates.append(datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute))


print('len(dates): {:,d}'.format(len(dates)))  # -> len(dates): 4,730,400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare attributes of the datetime object to the object itself, and that is what is causing the problem.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dates = []
date0 = datetime(2007, 1, 1, 0, 0)
delta = timedelta(minutes=1)


def get_leaps(startyear, endyear):
    leapyears = []
    for i in range(startyear, endyear):
        if (i%400 == 0)or ((i%4 == 0) and (i%100 != 0)):
            leapyears.append(i)
    for y in leapyears:
        for i in range(24):
            for j in range(60): 
                yield datetime(y, 2, 29, i, j))


while date0 < datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0):
    if date0 not in get_leaps(2007, 2016):
        dates.append(date0)
    date0 += delta
```

This should be the solution. This is by no means optimized and is very unpythonic, but see if you can improve it. I have a chemistry exam tomorrow and I don't have time. Cheers!

Comment: `i % 4 == 0` is not a valid leap year test.